“punto de inserción” en el final del renglon; Visual studio
No encuentro como colocar al final del renglon el “punto de inserción” en visual studio
cuando clickeo me genera espacio vacios y se ubica en el lugar seleccionado
alguno conoce como cambiar esta configuracion
dejo un video para que se entienda, en VSCode ya me vino predeterminado
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6VXUQ_8Bbk

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Vas a al menú superior:

Herramientas -> opciones

Luego buscas:

Editor de texto -> c# -> General

Y desmarcas la casilla "Habilitar espacio virtual"

